# when and why do we need to divide a class into many classes?

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns, coding-style

I am an android beginner developer. Currently, I am developing an application. However, my class is quite large because there are many UI components (to handle onClick, onProgressBarChanged, etc.).
Most of my components are dynamic. So, I have method to create those components.

Now I split some methods for initializing UI components into another class. 
At this point, I am trying to think/search for a good reason to split my class into several classes.

Advantage: maintainability, testability, reusability

Disadvantage: reduce runtime performance

I am not sure that there is any advantage or disadvantage that I have missed?

Furthermore, I will divide a class when I find an overlap method
I am not sure that there is another situation when a class must be divided.

Comment: Considering the number of libraries that you would import in any given project, runtime performance from splitting out your classes *alone* would be the least noticable of your "disadvantages".

Comment: I agree with @Makoto. If you have a class that you think it is a bit too big, it means YES it is too big. If you have a class that has too many responsibilities and when you want to describe it you use "and" then it is probably can be broken into single responsibility Like "Class saves vars and sync with network". Another good indication is if you can see inside your class a group of methods names are starting with verb and then Noun doing almost around the same thing then it means you better put them all in different class i.e savingFile, deletingFile, fetchingFile, renamingFile.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you've never looked into [refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring), then I would **strongly** encourage you to do so.  Martin Fowler has some excellent resources to get you started.  But, I'm getting slightly ahead of myself.

To begin with, you split out classes to maintain a clear delineation of responsibilities.  You can think of the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principle here - each class does one thing, and one thing very clearly.

If you notice that a *method*, let alone a *class*, is doing more than one thing, then that is a good time to stop and refactor - that is, take the code you have, and apply a particular, focused refactoring to it to improve readability and flow, while maintaining the same functionality.  You're essentially looking for [code smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) - parts of the code that are suspect, not following a specific contract or methodology, or are legitimate [anti-patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) - which are, themselves, practices that developers strive to *avoid*.

Programs that deal with UI (especially in Java) tend to be pretty verbose.  What you should avoid doing is placing any conditional business logic in the UI layer, for ease of separability, testing and clarity.  Make use of the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern to understand and abstract away the necessary separations between the UI (Views), and the actual work that's needed to be done (Controllers), while maintaining some semblance of state (Models).

Comment: +1 for Martirn Fowler book. I have the PDF and last week I ordered the Hard Copy. Also Lynda.com has a very good course on the Refactoring if you some quick notes on refactoring.

Answer (score -2):

We use OOPs Concept in Android(core java) Application Development. If we split our one class in many class it gives a good sense of maintainability, re-usability, Security and Easy change  in Coding during Development.
   As for example:- Util class for Database handling, Network Class for Internet connection , Dialog class for different type dialog and so... 
  This way we can categories our coding and  change or re use it any time. So it is good practice to follow the OOPS concept  during Development.

Thanks

Comment: You can still have SQL injection exploits and painful changes in code that is separated. It might make it easier or nicer to expose those issues, but you won't have security right off the bat from single-responsibility classes.